# Keith Wood Datepick inMonth Variable

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm using Keith Wood's Datepick, and am trying to block out specific ranges of dates using the `onDate` function found [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html).

What is the value and purpose of the `inMonth` parameter? My Rails website gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateClass' of undefined` when I include the `if (inMonth)` statement seen in the "National days" example in the above link to Keith Wood's site.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to something else, but the `inMonth` variable is to ensure that the function used in the `onDate` parameter doesn't apply to dates from other months that are displayed in the current month. For example, it prevents an `onDate` style from applying to March 30 when you're in the month of April.

Answer (score 0):

function onDate must return value look like that 
`{ dateClass: 'CSSclassName', selectable: true, title: ''}`